# How to create a huge sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create a very huge sparse matrix which has a shape `(447957347, 5027974)`.
And, it contains 3,289,288,566 elements.

But, when i create a `csr_matrix` using `scipy.sparse`, it return something like this:

```
<447957346x5027974 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.uint32'>'
    with -1005678730 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The source code for creating matrix is:

```
indptr = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint32)    # a is a python array('L') contain row index information
indices = np.array(b, dtype=np.uint32)   # b is  a python array('L') contain column index information
data = np.ones((len(indices),), dtype=np.uint32)
test = csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr), shape=(len(indptr)-1, 5027974), dtype=np.uint32)
```

And, I also found when I convert an 3 billion length python array to numpy array, it will raise an error:

```
ValueError:setting an array element with a sequence
```

But, when I create three 1 billion length python arrays, and convert them to numpy array, then append them. It works fine.

I'm confused.

Comment: Rather than describing `a` and `b` can you add some code that generates example data?

Comment: @Ofey Perhaps you can use the coo_matrix to create your sparse matrix, which seems easier than your current approach: `test = coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(m, n))`

Comment: Are you using 32-bit python or a 32-bit system? Sounds like you're hitting a 32-bit signed integer limit.

Comment: @jrennie I'm using 64-bit platform:'2.7.6 (default, Jan 16 2014, 04:27:03) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]' and i used the 32-bit unsigned int

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using an older version of SciPy. In the original implementation of sparse matrices, indices where stored in an `int32` variable, even on 64 bit systems. Even if you define them to be `uint32`, as you did, they get casted. So whenever your matrix has more than `2^31 - 1` nonzero entries, as is your case, the indexing overflows and lots of bad things happen. Note that in your case the weird negative number of elements is explained by:

```
>>> np.int32(np.int64(3289288566))
-1005678730
```

The good news is that this has already been figured out. I think [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3224) is the relevant PR, although there were some more fixes after that one. In any case, if you use the [latest release candidate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/) for SciPy 0.14, your problem should be gone.

Comment: It works，Thx! I think if scipy leave a interface to set the index datatype would be great. Actually, int64 waste some space ;)

Comment: Scipy (>= 0.14.0) uses the smallest integer size necessary.